# Apache Spark app workflow

Tags: apache-spark, workflow

How do You organize the Spark development workflow?

My way:

1. Local hadoop/yarn service.
2. Local spark service.
3. Intellij on one screen
4. Terminal with running sbt console
5. After I change Spark app code, I switch to terminal and run "package" to compile to jar and "submitSpark" which is stb task that runs spark-submit
6. Wait for exception in sbt console :)

I also tried to work with spark-shell:

1. Run shell and load previously written app.
2. Write line in shell
3. Evaluate it
4. If it's fine copy to IDE
5. After few 2,3,4, paste code to IDE, compile spark app and start again

Is there any way to develop Spark apps faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I develop the core logic of our Spark jobs using an interactive environment for rapid prototyping. We use the [Spark Notebook](https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook) running against a development cluster for that purpose.

Once I've prototyped the logic and it's working as expected, I "industrialize" the code in a Scala project, with the classical build lifecycle: create tests; build, package and create artifacts by Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I found writing scripts and using :load / :copy streamlined things a bit since I didn't need to package anything. If you do use sbt I suggest you start it and use `~ package` such that it automatically packages the jar when changes are made. Eventually of course everything will end up in an application jar, this is for prototyping and exploring.

1. Local Spark
2. Vim
3. Spark-Shell
4. APIs
5. Console

Answer (score 1):

We develop ours applications using an IDE (Intellij because we code your spark's applications in Scala) using scalaTest for testing.

In those tests we use local[*] as SparkMaster in order to allow the debugging.

For integration testing we used Jenkins and we launch an "end to end" script as an Scala application.

I hope this will be useful